# Rotate camera around the scene

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js

I would like to rotate my camera 90 degrees around the scene. I have tried using

```
cosole.log(camera.position);
```

and setting the camera to my desired position that I have seen in the log but this simply won't work.

This is how the camera is initialized (for the first image):

```
var width  = window.innerWidth,
    height = window.innerHeight;
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, width / height, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, -22, 22);
```

That's what I have:

[image]

That's what I would like to have (90 degrees counter-clockwise camera turn):

[image]

**EDIT**

I have noticed that I can rotate the object itself (: doing this :

```
plane.rotation.z = 90 * Math.PI / 180;
```

but I am still curious how to achieve the same effect with rotating the camera.

Answer (score 2):

You have to move the camera position in a circle, the lookAt position should be the object or scene:

```
var rotSpeed = .02 
camera.position.x = x * Math.cos(rotSpeed) - z * Math.sin(rotSpeed);
camera.position.z = z * Math.cos(rotSpeed) + x * Math.sin(rotSpeed);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
```

That's clockwise, for the other direction swap the plus and minus.